# Elastic Search Index in python

Tags: python, elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-4, pyelasticsearch

I want to push my data from a dictionary to Elasticsearch. How can I create an index for the same?

I tried using the Curl commands as well on Linux server
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/osint/' -d '
index:
  number_of_shards: 5
  number_of_replicas: 2
'
but this also didnt help out

I wrote this but couldn't fetch data through KibanaHud with index `osint` :

```
es.index(index='osint', doc_type='tweet', body=dict, id = 1)

es.indices.refresh(index='osint')
```

Can you please help

Comment: Adding a document should create the index.  Check the response from es.index().

Comment: I tried to check result on kibana hud but it doesnt load

Comment: on console it prints but on kibana it doesnt appear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try

```
curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/<index>/_mapping?pretty
```

I think you are missing on this